# Angular 2 calling ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call a WebAPI using Angular but running into a credential not authorized issue. It works fine in IE but in Chrome and FF (401 unauthorized), the credentials are not forwarded.

I think the solution is to add the default credential into the call in Angular, but I am not sure how to do it or maybe there is some other solution.

Angular calls

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class MyListService{

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getMyList() {
    //return an observable
    return this._http.get('http:////localhost:2311/api/MyListApi')

        .map((response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
        //.retry(3);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
return this._http.get('http:////localhost:2311/api/MyListApi', {
        credentials: RequestCredentialsOpts.Include
    }).map((response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
    }
```

Looks like a recent [fix](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5501) for Angular2. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905399/angular-2-http-request-does-not-send-credentials) answer.

Comment: It looks like you can only specify url, method, search, headers and body in [RequestOptionsArgs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html).  I am running  angular2 2.0.0-beta.17 in my environment.  I can't be the only one with this issue?

Comment: mmm have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905399/angular-2-http-request-does-not-send-credentials?lq=1 maybe can give you some help.

Comment: Patched recently so you can use   withCredentials, true in the call. Watch out for CORS needs if running over different server/ports

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well. My Angular2-rc4 app calls a .NET Core 1.0.0 WebAPI app on another domain.. posting this in case it may help others.

As mentioned by others, in Angular2 pass withCredentials true:

```
getUser() {
    return this.http.get(this._apiUrl + "/account/GetUser", { withCredentials: true })
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

In your WebAPI project you can set CORS policies in Startup.cs (instead of web.config):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
    corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
    corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
    corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin();
    corsBuilder.AllowCredentials();
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", corsBuilder.Build());
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
}
```

Of course, set your policies based on your app's needs, this just allows all for testing. Example [here](https://manuel-rauber.com/2016/03/29/node-js-asp-net-core-1-0-a-usage-comparison-part-4-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) and official .NET Core docs [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html) provide more details.